# Amplify.js + Asp.net Web Api send multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, amplifyjs

js code to define an ajax call:

```
function InitDataServices() 
{    
    amplify.request.decoders.myDecoder =
    function (data, status, xhr, success, error) 
    {
      if (status === "success")           {
         success(data);
      } else if (status === "fail" || status === "error") {
        error(message, status);
    } else {
        error(message, "fatal");
    }
};

amplify.request.define("Emision_FiltrarSeguros", "ajax", {
    url: "http://localhost:63721/api/emision/filtrar",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    decoder: "myDecoder"
});
}
```

Then the code to make the actual ajax call is:

```
function Emision_FiltrarSeguros(requestData,okFunction, failFunction) 
{
     amplify.request({
    resourceId: "Emision_FiltrarSeguros",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    success: function (data) {
        okFunction(data);
    },
    error: function (message, level) {
        failFunction(message,level);
    }
});
};
```

And finally this code in the page to make the call:

```
function FiltrarSeguros()
    {   
        this.request = {Ramo:-1, 
                        NroSocio: 107701,
                        NroSeguro:-1,
                        NroEndoso:-1,
                        Vigentes:0,
                        Patente:"" };
        Emision_FiltrarSeguros(request,okFiltrarSeguros, failFiltrarSeguros);
    }
```

The controller code is this:

```
public List<FiltroSeguroResponse> Filtrar(FiltroSeguroRequest request)
    {
        return DLL.Service.EmisionService.FiltrarSeguros(request, "jdh");
    }
```

The problem is that the data that i POST from the page never get mapped to the request (of type FiltroSeguroRequest, whose properties are the same as the object literal I build in the ajax call) parameter.
What is wrong??? Thanks.

Comment: Could you share how your raw request(from Fiddler probably) looks like?

Comment: did you manage to get this working as i am also facing the same issue,

Answer (score 0):

Add the content-type to where you define your amplify request like this:

```
amplify.request.define("Emision_FiltrarSeguros", "ajax", {
    url: "http://localhost:63721/api/emision/filtrar",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    decoder: "myDecoder",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
});
```